# Reading JSON from gigabytes of .txt files and add to the same list

Tags: python, json

I have 300 `txt` files (each between 80-100mb) that I should have to put to a `list` object and using the all content in the same time. I already created a working solution, but unfortunately it crashes due `MemoryError` when I load more than 3 txt-s. I'm not sure that it matters but I have a lot of ram so I could easily load 30GB to the memory if it can solve the problem.

Basically I would like to loop through the 300 `txt` files inside the same for loop. Is it possible to create a list object that holds 30GB of content?  Or achieve it in any different way? I would really appreciate if somebody could explain me the ideal solution or any useful tips.

Here is how I tried, it produces the Memory Error after loading 3 txt.

```
def addContentToList(filenm):
    with open(filenm, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as v: 
        jsonContentTxt.extend(json.load(v))

def createFilenameList(name):
    for r in range(2,300):
        file_str = "%s%s.txt" % (name, r,)
        filenames.append(file_str)


filename1 = 'log_1.txt'
filename2 = 'log_'
filenames = []

jsonContentTxt = []

with open(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:    

    jsonContentTxt = json.load(f)

createFilenameList(filename2)

for x in filenames:
    addContentToList(x)


json_data = json.dumps(jsonContentTxt)

content_list = json.loads(json_data)

print (content_list)
```

Comment: you should probably be storing them in a database instead of holding them in memory ...

Comment: Which line of code it crashes on?

Comment: @gatto you are using python 32-bit ... 32 bit programs have a hard limit of 2gb of memory for any program ... switch to 64 bit will sort of solve your problem (the memory error at least, it wont do much about the fact that holding them in memory is not a good solution to this problem) ...

Comment: @warmoverflow it would have to be on a `json.loads` line (or maybe the `list.extend`) ... but knowing that really wont help solve this problem much

Comment: @JoranBeasley I would like to avoid using a database, because on the other side I have to upload a lot of data, and overall it would be more comfortable to do it locally.

Answer (score 2):

[Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the European currency systems.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)

Text files are a **really** bad idea to store data like this. You should use a database. I recommend [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) and [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

Apart from that, your error is probably due to using a 32-bit version of Python (which will cap your memory allocation to 2GB), use 64-bit instead. Even so I think you'd be better off by using a more proper tool for the job and **not** allocating 30GB of memory space.

Comment: @gatto Databases don't have to be hosted on the cloud. You can perfectly have a local database. [Read more](https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html).

Comment: It would be the best to avoid using a database, because I don't wanna upload that much data to another database. The ideal would be if I could do it locally.

Comment: @gatto As I have said to the comment you deleted, databases don't have to be remotely hosted, they can perfectly be local.

Comment: I will second(or even re-third?) the database recommendation ... even given OP's comments....